# Importing the module and importing a class or Enum from the same module

Tags: python, import

```
from x.y import SomeEnum
from x import y
```

`SomeEnum` is a Enum
y here is a module name in which `SomeEnum` is defined.

Main reason for doing such kind of imports is I don't want long names during accessing something from `SomeEnum`

Is it a good practice to do such imports?

Comment: Just put this` from x.y import SomeEnum` into __init__.py  of module x if you want to ignore typing this import in every script. Everything else is just fine

Comment: I am using python3.8. I think init.py is not required anymore. I don't want to use a separate file as well

Comment: @AdnanAhmed `__init__.py`

Comment: @Praburaj not required but can by useful sometimes

Comment: Yes correct. I don't want to use __init__.py file. I am not trying to avoid importing. Just wanted to know whatever I mentioned in the question is a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. There's no such hard and fast rule for this. However make sure you know the difference between

```py
import foo
```

and

```py
from foo import bar
```

In the second one bar gets into the scope of the importing module.
Here's a reference, it will help you understand the difference
https://realpython.com/python-import/.